# Elastic search query date range failed using querystring

Tags: string, date, elasticsearch, kibana

My record is like 
`joinedDate:March 22nd 2018, 17:45:02.000`, and I use query string `joinedDate:{* TO 2018-06-12}`, which failed. This operation took place in Kibana web page.

Could someone tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Please share the mapping of your inedx. `GET index_name/_mapping`.

Comment: I don't know that, all I use is a `<input>` and a search button

Comment: Can you try it in the same time format as the record.

Comment: Yeah I've tried and failed, the field type is `date`, I use query string `joinedDate:"March 22nd 2018, 17:45:02.000"`

Comment: Are you sure `joined Date` is of type `date` ? Try running `GET index_name/_mapping` in kibana

Comment: Yes, I checked that in the kibana management page. Sorry I don't know how to send that request, I don't have a server, I tried replace the string after `kibana#/` and it failed

Comment: In Kibana you can run the query in dev tools section

Comment: I've done that the type is `date` and format is `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z`, maybe the format's problem?

Comment: Yes I think so. How were you able to index the date in the format specified above then??

Comment: 2018/06/13 12:00:00 -0700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the format set in `mapping`, need to apply to that.
For format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z`, need string query like `2018/06/13 12:00:00 -0700`